# How do I suppress output from multiple threads when running cargo test?

Tags: unit-testing, debugging, rust, rust-cargo

If I execute the below testcases with `cargo test`, the output of `one_thread_test` will be suppressed as stated in the documentation.

However the output from `multi_thread_test` will appear on stdout. Is it possible to match the behavior of single- and multi-threaded testcases?

```
#[test]
fn one_thread_test() {
    println!("A");
    println!("B");
}

#[test]
fn multi_thread_test() {
    use std::thread;

    let mut threads = vec![];
    for _ in 0..100 {
        let t = thread::spawn(move || {
            println!("from thread");
        });
        threads.push(t);
    }
    for thread in threads {
        thread.join().unwrap();
    }
}
```

Comment: @PeterHall The problem is that `cargo` does not hide stdout as in your link above in multi thread test case.

Comment: Oh I see. You can workaround it by implementing your own `print`, which writes to a shared buffer, and only print from the buffer in the main thread. Could be overly complex though..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick-and-dirty workaround.

It works by sending messages to a receiver owned by a struct in the main thread. The receiver prints all of the accumulated messages when it is dropped - this is important so that panics caused by failed assertions don't prevent the printing.

```
use std::sync::mpsc::{channel, Sender, Receiver};

struct TestPrinter {
    receiver: Receiver<String>,
    sender: Sender<String>,
}

impl TestPrinter {
    fn new() -> TestPrinter {
        let (sender, receiver) = channel();
        TestPrinter { receiver, sender }
    }

    fn sender(&self) -> Sender<String> {
        self.sender.clone()
    }
}

impl Drop for TestPrinter {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        while let Some(v) = self.receiver.try_recv().ok() {
            println!("later: {}", v);
        }
    }
}
```

And a convenience macro so it feels mostly like calling `println!`:

```
macro_rules! myprint {
    ($send: expr, $($arg:tt)*) => { 
        (*&$send).send(format!($($arg)*));
     };
}
```

In order to send messages for printing, you have get a `sender` for each thread:

```
#[test]
fn multi_thread_test() {
    use std::thread;

    let mut threads = vec![];
    let printer = TestPrinter::new();

    for _ in 0..100 {
        let sender = printer.sender();
        let t = thread::spawn(move || {
            myprint!(sender, "from thread");
        });
        threads.push(t);
    }

    for thread in threads {
        thread.join().unwrap();
    }
}
```

The actual printing happens when `printer` goes out of scope. It's in the main thread so it won't print during successful tests unless `--nocapture` is specified.

Comment: But is this bug in `cargo` and I should reports the issue, or this intented behaviour and should use your hack always when for some reason I need multiply threads in my test?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's technically a bug. But it might be seen that way, and there is no harm in reporting it.

Comment: Thank your for answer and reply, I submit issue here: https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/6350 and will wait one day before accept answer, may be somebody suggest something else.